# ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}$ series convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series
$$
\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}
$$ convergent or divergent? I have verified with root test and ratio test that are not applicable.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}\to \frac 1 e$.

Comment: $$\frac{n^n}{(1+n)^{1+n}}=\frac{(1+\frac1n)^{-n}}{1+n}=\frac{e^{-n\ln(1+\frac1n)}}{1+n}=\frac {e^{-1+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{3n^2}+\frac1{4n^3}-...}}{1+n}>\frac {e^{-1-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{3n^2}-\frac1{4n^3}-...}}{1+n}$$
$$>\frac {e^{-1-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{2n^3}-...}}{1+n}=\frac {e^{-1-\frac1{2(n-1)}}}{1+n}>\frac{e^{-\frac32}}{n+1}\,\text{for}\,n>1$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav, thank you for the response. Can we conclude that the series is divergent.

Comment: @geetha290krm, thank you for the response.

Comment: Yes, based on geetha290km's hint, the series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series...